# Any techniques for finding integer values of a trigonometric expression?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

I am working on a problem, and came across the following expression after some manipulations:

$\cfrac{sin(\frac{\pi k}{m})}{sin(\frac{\pi}{m})} - \cfrac{sin(\frac{\pi}{m})}{sin(\frac{\pi k}{m})} $.

To find an answer to my question, I would need to know for what positive integers $k$ and $m$ (with $k<m$) this expression is a positive integer (or that there aren't any besides in 2 cases), two known solutions are $k=2$, $m=5$, and $k=3$, $m=8$.

I have spent much time thinking about the question, and I feel as if I am lacking some key idea necessary to try to answer this question. Are there any methods for determining when this expression is a positive integer?

Comment: Using  [Weierstrass transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) you can turn this into asking for integers values of a polynomial.

Comment: How exactly would this work though, since the expression contains trigonometric expressions of different angles?

Comment: You can use formulas for trigonometric functions of multiple angles, no?

Comment: You could, except there isn't a pattern to the multiple angle identities as you vary the multiple. Multiple angle identities are useful for if I fix $m$, but I want to know more generally for all $m$ and $k$ if there are solutions. Multiple angle identities don't really help when I'm looking at infinitely many multiples of angles - although please correct me if I'm thinking about this the wrong way.

Comment: Well, the polynomials that give those multiple angle identities are (essentially) Tchebychev polynomials. Expressing the problem in terms of them allows you to look for all sort of properties of these polynomials... It's not like they are random! Expressing everything in terms of hypergeometric functionbs might also help. Who knows.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this!